# Having an active state toggler on multiple buttons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am trying to have my buttons light up once clicked, and dim when clicked twice. To indicate the user has already clicked that button.

```
 const [isActive, setActive] = useState("false");
const handleToggle = () => {
  setActive(!isActive);
};
```

And my buttons are toggling with the following code

```
<button
            type="button"
            value="Peperoni, "
            className={isActive ? "button btn first" : "button btn firstActive"}
            onClick={(event) => {
              ToppingPlusMinus(event);
            }}
          >
            Pepperoni
          </button>
```

So far I have this working, however the buttons are all tied to the same state so when one is clicked they all light up. I am stumped on how to downsize this and make each button toggle its active class individually.

I'm aware I could just brute force it with many states for each button, but I know there is a smarter solution on there.

Thank you in advance for your time.
My full code is on a codesandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-dirac-k99g7?file=/src/App.js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to create a component that tracks its own state and fires the onClick

```js
const ButtonClickable = props => {
 const [isActive, setActive] = useState(false);
 const handleToggle = (ev) => {
  setActive(!isActive);
  props.onClick && props.onClick(props.value)
 };
  return <button
            type="button"
            className={isActive ? "button btn first" : "button btn firstActive"}
            onClick={handleToggle}
          >
            {props.value}
          </button>

}
```

Then in the parent compoennt

```js
<ButtonClickable onClick={ToppingPlusMinus} value="Peperoni, "/>
<ButtonClickable onClick={ToppingPlusMinus} value="Other, "/>
<ButtonClickable onClick={ToppingPlusMinus} value="Milk, "/>
```

Note that `ToppingPlusMinus` becomes `ToppingPlusMinus(value)`

Comment: So I tried this and it appears to break my method of adding it to my array. Since my method of getting it in the array relys on the ```value```

Comment: you can pass `value="Peperoni, "` as a prop to `ButtonClickable` and then onClick will pass that as well. See the updated answer

Comment: After pasting your new code into my component, and setting up my parent like this ```   <ButtonClickable onCLick={ToppingPlusMinus} value="Peperoni, " />``` It is still not recognizing the value

Comment: Not sure what you mean by not recognizing the value but i've correct my example